# jQuery JSON API call not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, api

I'm trying to make an API call to a Minecraft api that returns, along others, a status message, and then print it out on the site. For that I'm using an AJAX JSON call, getting the entered string to connect to the API and to GET the information about the server in a function (which I'm pretty sure is the most common way to do that).

However, when I try and enter a (working) IP, it displays the *researching data...* message very briefly and then clears the field again. Nothing appears, even though there should be a status massage from the API. It doesn't even log in the console.

Any help on that?

JS Code:

```
function getStatus(){
var ip = $("#ip").val(); //getting the value from the textbox
if(ip == ""){
    $("#addmes").html("<h1>you didn't enter anything -.-</h1>"); //checking if anything is entered
} else {
    $("#addmes").html("<h1>researching data...</h1>"); //displaying a temporary status message
    $.getJSON("http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip="+ ip + "&callback=?", function(json){ //connecting to the API, using the IP variable in the process
        console.log(json); //console log
        $("#addmes").html("<h1>" + json[0].status + "</h1>"); //printing out the API status message
    })
}

}
```

API response (tested with http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip=mc.hypixel.net&callback=?):

```
?({"status":"success","ip":"mc.hypixel.net","port":25565,"last_update":"2013-12-19 09:09:58","online":true,"motd":"\u00a7aHypixel Lobby \u00a76| \u00a7cPlay Now!                                     \u00a7eMega Walls \u00a7aPublic BETA!","players":{"max":16001,"online":6989,"list":false},"version":"1.7.2","favicon":false});
```

Comment: Navigate directly to the url+ip (using your web browser) and post what is returned here.

Comment: Does url directly in browser work? what does it return?

Comment: Okay, I'll post the API response.

Comment: Does adding a second `?` to `&callback=?` help? `&callback=??` what version of jquery is this

Comment: @KevinB Directly like this maybe? http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip=mc.hypixel.net&callback=jsonp

Comment: I see a possible issue... that linebreak in your message of the day... do you own this api?

Comment: It doesn't work even if no callback is used. The jQuery version is 2.0.3.

Comment: @KevinB It looks normal if you visit the response page directly, I'm pretty sure the code is just messed up on here.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the jquery code you are using other than `?` should be `??`, that's why I'm asking about the api.

Comment: `json[0].status` is not how you access the data.  `json` is an object, not an array.  It should be `json.status`.  Fix that and it works.  http://jsfiddle.net/R3aUG/

Comment: i doubted that was the only issue due to *"It doesn't even log in the console."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this url:

```
http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip=mc.hypixel.net&callback=jsonp
```

Your original url with just ? returns without function name in the beginning. I'm not sure if jsonp without function name is possible or not, but you can check...

It works here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yj467/1/

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip=mc.hypixel.net&callback=?", function( json ) {
  console.log( json );
  $(".status").html(json.status);
});
```

Comment: jQuery should be filling that part in for you

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it wouldn't even work without a callback.

Comment: You want `callback=?`.  jQuery will replace the `?` with a generated function name.

Comment: @Alyn check my jsfiddle, simplified all it works fine!

Comment: @salivan actually worked! I must have been doing something wrong

Comment: @Alyn :) I think your if else statement is problem. Check with console.log("yes") if it is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

The response doesn't look like an Array. It is just an object. Try using just json.status, instead of json[0].status.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** I read up on the documentation of getJSON and it seems it does automatically recognize JSONP requests. Leaving the post here in case it's helpful to someone

I suspect you're being scuppered by the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

If you're (as I suspect) not actually the programmer of syfaro.net and you're not running this script on that server, you won't be able to access the page.

Helpfully, to get around this people created JSONP, which is a rather nasty hack it its way but will let you do what you're after.

You can use it like this:

```
function getStatus(){
  var ip = $("#ip").val(); //getting the value from the textbox
  if(ip == ""){
    $("#addmes").html("<h1>you didn't enter anything -.-</h1>"); //checking if anything is entered
  } else {
    $("#addmes").html("<h1>researching data...</h1>"); //displaying a temporary status message

    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'text/javascript';
    script.src= 'http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip="+ ip + "&callback=jsonCallback';
    head.appendChild(script);
  }
}

function jsonCallback(json){
  $("#addmes").html("<h1>" + json[0].status + "</h1>"); //printing out the API status message
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3VZuP/

Comment: This is what jquery is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: He *IS* using JSONP.  `callback=?` tells jQuery to do this for you.

Comment: This solution won't work, as the response doesn't set a variable. You would be importing a script with an object that isn't assigned to a variable, and therefore have no way to reference it.

Comment: @bic incorrect, it would be executing a function with said object as a parameter, jquery defines said function and passes it's name to the callback parameter. The code in this answer will work, but i doubt it has anything to do with the problem.